# Django: Uploaded Filename Issue

Tags: django, django-models

In my django app i'm trying to resize & compress an Image before saving it to the database.

Here's how I did it inside the `models`

```
class Data(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='all_images/', null=True, blank=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.image:
        img = Image.open(self.image)
        resize = img.resize((240, 240), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        new_image = BytesIO()
        resize.save(new_image, format=img.format, quality=80, save=False)
        temp_name = os.path.split(self.image.name)[1]
        self.image.save(temp_name, content=ContentFile(new_image.getvalue()), save=False)
    super(Data, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here's the problem, I saved an image named `tesla.jpg` into the database, it compressed & resized it well, but it renamed it something like, `tesla_CKBw0Kr_iWKC4Ry_ucPoh4b_BB2C8Ck_WrfWkPR_Tzig2T1_tdhst4b_3Bysn6k_i4ffhPR_yhig2T1.jpg`

I'm worried about the new name because normally it should be `tesla_CKBw0Kr.jpg` or something smaller, so what's the problem in my code & how can we fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Django mangles the image filename so that you don't run into filename collisions in the filesystem. Consider what if you had to save another image named `tesla.jpg` and don't want it to accidentally overwrite the first one.

You don't have to worry about that though. Django stores the real, original filename in the [UploadeFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.name) object.

**UPDATE**

Django will keep adding random characters to the filename if you upload more files with the same filename:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/storage.py#L60-L89

If you worry about hitting the filesystem's filename length limit, then set an appropriate max_length on the ImageField. The function will then keep truncating the file_name and generating new names within the filename length limit, until it finds a free name.